# Creating custom HTML info windows for markers in using the Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps

I'm creating an array of information to populate markers using the Google Maps API.

How can I use the following script to add html to the markers?

The array while be built in a php loop.

```
var markers = [];
var title = [];

var point = new GLatLng(51.505804230524056,-0.11801719665527344);
marker = new GMarker(point);
map.addOverlay(marker);
markers[0] = marker;
title[0] = "marker 0";

var point = new GLatLng(51.45400691005981,-0.263671875);
marker = new GMarker(point);
map.addOverlay(marker);
markers[1] = marker;
title[1] = "marker 1";
```

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: @gareth: You may want to revise the question to make it more clear. Tell us what you tried in the "php loop", for example... In addition, it would also help if you can mark as accepted some of your previous questions. This will help you getting more answers in future questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [v2.0 of the API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/)? If so, I'd *strongly* recommend creating an RSS/XML/KML feed from your site and then using the [GGeoXml class](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GGeoXml) to create an overlay from that feed.

If you are using [v3.0 of the API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/), then the [GGeoXml class is not available](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/56d8b07a3c1df448), however, a the [geoxml3 library](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) has been developed to allow for just *KML* files.

That being said, if you want to directly add the markers in v2.0, you would call the [bindInfoWindow](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMarker.bindInfoWindow), [bindInfoWindowHtml](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMarker.bindInfoWindowHtml), [bindInfoWindowTabs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMarker.bindInfoWindowTabs) or [bindWindowInfoTabsHtml](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMarker.bindInfoWindowTabsHtml) methods on the [GMarker](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMarker) instances you are creating in order to set the HTML displayed when the marker is clicked.

In v3.0 of the API, you would create an instance of the [InfoWindow class](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#InfoWindow) and then call the open method, passing the optional anchor parameter, which represents the [MVCObject instance](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#MVCObject) (which in this case is your [Marker instance](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#Marker)).